# Why is my unlist result shorter than my list?

Tags: r

Why does unlisting my list data structure result in a different length? The length of the list is `13951`. The length of the unlisted result is `13654`. There are no `NULL`'s or `NA`'s.

```
> class(price)
[1] "list"

> head(price)
$`570`
[1] 0

$`440`
[1] 0

$`730`
[1] 1499

$`304930`
[1] 0

$`550`
[1] 1999

$`230410`
[1] 0

length(names(price))  # 13951
length(price)         # 13951
length(unlist(price)) # 13654

> sum(is.na(price))
[1] 0
> sum(is.null(price))
[1] 0
```

How do I ensure the unlist length is the same as the list length?

-- ATTEMPTED SOLUTION BELOW:

```
> out <- do.call(c, lapply(price, (function(x) {
+   if (is.null(x)) {NA} else { x } 
+ })))
> length(out) #2
[1] 13654


> table(sapply(price, class))

numeric 
  13951
```

Comment: to check `NULL` elements, use `length(sapply(price,is.null))`

Comment: Can you run `table(sapply(price, class))`  and let us know?

Answer (score 7):

One thing is to count elements in the list. Another is to count their lengths...

```
a.list <- list(a= 1, b= NULL, c = list())
length(a.list) # 3
sum(lengths(a.list)) # 1 {as suggested by Nicola}
# same as: sum(sapply(a.list, length)) # 1
```

I assume you have named list elements that are NULL (or length == 0). When you unlist, those should be lost.

```
length(unlist(a.list)) #1
```

If you want to extract something from all named elements (replacing a NULL with a NA) you could do as follows.

```
out <- do.call(c, lapply(a.list, (function(x) {
  if (is.null(x) | length(x) == 0) {NA} else { x } 
})))
length(out) #3
```

This assumes you have no 2-level lists.

Comment: To count number of 0 length elements in a list `sum(lengths(a.list) == 0L)`. Also note that `length(NULL)` returns 0.